# soul's \ul{} breaks wrapfigure and textflow?

Tags: wrapfigure, ulem, soul

Please, I have a nice picture without that `\ul{...}`, but i need that.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[3]{l}{30mm}
\Huge 1
\end{wrapfigure}

\ul{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Suspendisse nec dolor eget tortor iaculis molestie et ac diam.
Aliquam feugiat tempus orci et suscipit.
Morbi varius dignissim arcu, vitae facilisis metus imperdiet id.
Morbi non mi at neque mollis elementum.
Etiam mauris velit, accumsan in fringilla nec, auctor in eros.
Etiam porta fermentum pretium. 

\end{document}
```

With that \ul{...} paragraph is being stretched to full width and figure goes away to the left. What is wrong?

Thanks!

ps. Actually there are graphics in `wrapfigure`s and i really need some words to be underlined. Yes, `ulem`'s `\emph` does the same as `\ul`. Well, yes, `\underline` does right thing here, but i am unhappy with `\underline`.

**Update**:
With this addition:

```
\usepackage{color}
...
% instead of just \Huge 1:
\fcolorbox[gray]{0.59}{1}{\parbox{30mm}{\Huge 1}}
```

and after making "just too long word" `pdflatex` produces this picture:
[image: hyphenation does work!]

So, paragraph is nicely stretched to \textwidth;

Comment: I guess `\ul` breaks hyphenation. Does adding explicit hyphenation work? `\ul{longword\-with\-explicit\-hyphens}`

Comment: Huh. It's not that at all. This is weird. If you make the beginning of the text `L\ul{orem ipsum...}` then it works fine...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `wrapfig` to work properly it needs to see a paragraph. You can force a paragraph by 
using `\leavevmode`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[3]{l}{30mm}
\Huge 1
\end{wrapfigure}
\leavevmode\ul{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Suspendisse nec dolor eget tortor iaculis molestie et ac diam.
Aliquam feugiat tempus orci et suscipit.
Morbi varius dignissim arcu, vitae facilisis metus imperdiet id.
Morbi non mi at neque mollis elementum.
Etiam mauris velit, accumsan in fringilla nec, auctor in eros.
Etiam porta fermentum pretium. 

\end{document}
```

You could also use a `noindent` or `quitvmode` or use a `rule` as per Seamus post.

Comment: So `\ul` confuses wrapfig into thinking there's no paragraph there?

Comment: @Seamus `\ul` makes sure it does not start a new one, otherwise it would break things in other places.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why this works, or what's going on, but this does make things work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[3]{l}{30mm}
\Huge 1
\end{wrapfigure}
\rule{0pt}{0pt}\ul{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Suspendisse nec dolor eget tortor iaculis molestie et ac diam.
Aliquam feugiat tempus orci et suscipit.
Morbi varius dignissim arcu, vitae facilisis metus imperdiet id.
Morbi non mi at neque mollis elementum.
Etiam mauris velit, accumsan in fringilla nec, auctor in eros.
Etiam porta fermentum pretium. 

\end{document}
```

All I've done is put an invisible rule before your `\ul`

Comment: Hha-ha!! It looks like it does! I feel like i need to check it more (and would b great to understand what's going on) -- but THANK YOU. I need to check everything, i'll be back .)

Comment: `\rule` starts with `\leavevmode`, see Yiannis answer.