# \index causing spurious whitespace

Tags: spacing, indexing

I'm having a problem with the `\index` command causing unwanted whitespace:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\def \nothing #1{}

\begin{document}

\noindent The Principle of Availability\\\index{principle of availability}
What is said must be intuitively accessible to the conversational participants, 
unless something goes wrong and they cannot be counted as `normal interpreters'.

\end{document}
```

If this is compiled, the line starting with "What is said" has a slight indent. This indent is gone if I add a `\relax`, or a `%` after the `index{...}` command, I guess since that gobbles up the newline following it. If there is no index command at all (i.e. the line ends after the `\\`), or if I replace it by `\nothing{...}` the spurious whitespace is also gone.

If I change `\index` to `\nothing` and have `\nothing` insert an empty hbox by defining it `\def \nothing #1{\hbox{}}`, the problem is back again. So I guess `\index` inserts something that makes LaTeX no longer ignore the newline character.

Is there a way to prevent `\index` from causing whitespace?

Note that the above is actually the result of some macro expansions, so "just move the `\index` to the next line" isn't going to help me. Also, I tried wrapping `\index` in my own macro that inserts a `\relax` after it, but that didn't work either.

Comment: How about defining `\newcommand*{\myindex}[1]{\index{#1}\ignorespaces}` and using `\myindex` in the document?

Comment: Seemingly, since `\index` is after `\\ `, you *start a paragraph with it*.  I can't recall exactly, but `\index` does some funny things with surrounding spaces (see `source2e.pdf`), and probably this might not work in vertical mode.  You might thus try `\\\leavevmode\index{...}` (or `\newcommand\myindex[1]{\leavevmode\index{#1}}` or something similar).

Comment: I do not know the makro producing your text, but would
    'The Principle of Availability\index{principle of availability}\\' be possible for you?

Comment: @mbork No, after `\\ ` we are still in same paragraph.

Comment: @jfbu: maybe, I'm not sure. Maybe it's like this: after `\\` you are still in the same paragraph, but in vertical mode...

Comment: @mbork after `\\ ` you still are in horizontal mode `foo\\\relax\ifhmode OK\fi bar`

Comment: @jfbu: maybe, as I said, it was only a conjecture.

Answer (score 7):

In [`latex.ltx`](http://ctan.sqsol.co.uk/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx), the `\index` command is (properly) defined whenever you execute `\makeindex`. Otherwise it virtually does nothing.

*Skip over this part if you're not interested in the detail...*

---

The proper definition is

```
\show\index
> index=macro:
->\@bsphack \begingroup \@sanitize \@wrindex
```

while

```
\show\@wrindex
> \@wrindex=macro:
#1->\protected@write \@indexfile {}{\string \indexentry {#1}{\thepage }}\endgroup \@esphack
```

So, in essence, `\index` has this structure:

```
\@bsphack
\begingroup
...
\endgroup
\@esphack
```

Both `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack` act like grouping partners that perform certain operations before and after whatever it surrounds. This only happens while in horizontal mode<sup>1</sup>, which is the case with your example; `\index{...}` is placed after `\\` and is the first token of a paragraph. `\@esphack` is suppose to apply `\ignorespaces`, but this is **only** the case if the value of `\lastskip` was greater than `0pt`:

```
\show\@esphack
> \@esphack=macro:
-> \relax
   \ifhmode
     \spacefactor\@savsf
     \ifdim\@savsk>\z@
       \ignorespaces
     \fi
   \fi
```

Since there is no skip before `\index`, `\lastskip=0pt` and `\ignorespaces` never sees the light of day.

<sup>1</sup> Read [What are vertical and horizontal modes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13177/what-are-vertical-and-horizontal-modes) for more information on this.

---

*...aaaand, we're back!*

If you *must* use `\index`, then you could redefine it this way **after** `\makeindex`:

```
\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand*{\index}[1]{\oldindex{#1}\ignorespaces}
```

This stores `\index` in `\oldindex` and appends it with `\ignorespaces`, taking care of the spurious spaces immediately after `\\` as well as in the additional small case described above.

Alternatively, make your own index command

```
\newcommand*{\myindex}[1]{\index{#1}\ignorespaces}% \myindex{<entry>}
```

which does the same as above. However, it requires you using `\myindex` rather than `\index`.

Comment: There's no spurious space in `lorem ipsum \index{blah} lorem ipsum`. On the other hand, it's best to attach `\index` to the indexed word, so the reference is guaranteed to be correct: the space before `\index` might trigger a line break and the line might go to the *next* page (this is a very unfortunate combination of events, but Murphy's law is always valid).

Comment: @egreg: You're right. I was fiddling around with different styles to identify where to modify what, and perhaps left a change in that caused the `lorem ipsum \index{blah} lorem ipsum` spacing problem. I've removed that from my answer.

Comment: In the following code: `In first approximation, none of the intermediate frequency radiation comes back to the radio-frequency side of the mixer (this is however possible and is called ``IF feedback\index{IF feedback}'').`, redefining index (or defining myindex) to include `\ignorewhitespaces` does not remove the extra space before the closing double-quote.

Answer (score 1):

that is the default behaviour, use it always this way:

```
\noindent The Principle of Availability\\     
What\index{principle of availability} is said must be intuitively ...
```