# How to switch between horizontal and vertical modes?

Tags: spacing

I've got some complex code giving me an error:
`! You can't use '\vadjust' in vertical mode.`

So I presume I need to switch to the horizontal mode. I've found this question, "[What are vertical and horizontal modes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13177/7093)", but nothing explaining how to switch between them.

I've looked at the `TeXbook`, but nothing seems to answer this question.

How do switch between the two?

Comment: You don't want to switch to horizontal mode in order to use `\vadjust`; just say `\ifvmode<...>\else\vadjust{<...>}\fi`.

Comment: @egreg If I do the `\ifvmode` it ends up skipping the code which is supposed to typeset some numbers properly vertically spaced.

Comment: Sorry, but without seeing the code it's impossible to say more. But `\vadjust` is for adding vertical material when we're in horizontal mode, so I can't understand why you need to use it in the first place. However, the way to ensure being in horizontal mode (which starts a paragraph, if issued in vertical mode) is `\leavevmode`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The command `\vadjust` can be issued only in horizontal or inline math mode. Its purpose is to insert vertical material (for instance a vertical space) after the line where the command eventually ends up.

An example of `\vadjust` in LaTeX is given by `\vspace` that does (in the normal variant)

```
\ifvmode
  \vskip#1\vskip\z@skip
\else
  \@bsphack
  \vadjust{\@restorepar\vskip#1\vskip\z@skip}%
  \@esphack
\fi
```

Thus it just does a `\vskip` if already in vertical mode or it inserts a `\vadjust` item.

Sometimes `\vadjust` is used for “cheating”; an example is to add something to the left or right of a line without resorting to `\marginpar`. In this cases, horizontal mode must be ensured, which is obtained by issuing

```
\leavevmode
```

before `\vadjust`.