# Problems with aligning equal signs

Tags: align

Trying to align equal signs and get an error message saying

```
missing } inserted
```

I can't figure out what I've done wrong?

```
\begin{align}
($b^nn^\alpha$)$^{-1}$=\large$\frac{a^n}{n^\alpha}$
$\geq\frac{a^n}{n^p}$
\end{align}
```

Comment: Welcome. Do not use dollar signs (`$`) inside an equation.

Comment: Welcome to the site! And, equally, don't put `$ ... $` around individual units elsewhere, either. In LaTeX we treat a mathematical expression/equation/etc. as a single unit and it should all go in math mode, with any text or anything else marked up as such. But it'd be super important to have, in general, `$(b^nn^\alpha)^{-1}=\large\frac{a^n}{n^\alpha}$` (within `align`, which already puts you in math mode, you must not have the `$ ... $`). This treats the maths appropriately and will automatically handle things like correct spacing around the = sign

Comment: For more: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255073/im-trying-to-bold-this-set-of-code-t-1x-frac95x32/255077#255077 Also, you probably want `\dfrac`, rather than `\large`, or - in general - to be in a display math environment

Comment: The title of your posting -- Problems with aligning equal signs -- doesn't seem to correspond to the equation you've provided, as there's only one `=` symbol in the entire expression. Please edit either the title or the body of the posting to provide more consistency.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me, as you should read some [introductory material](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner) to LaTeX (see also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84384/latex-introductions-in-languages-other-than-english)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  (b^n n^\alpha)^{-1}
  &= \frac{a^n}{n^\alpha} \\
  &\geq\frac{a^n}{n^p}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image]