# Where can I find documentation for the \nolinebreak command?

Tags: line-breaking

Where can I find documentation on how to use the `\nolinebreak` command?

The [Guide to LaTeX2e for Authors](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/usrguide.pdf) at [latex-project.org](http://www.latex-project.org) never makes mention of `\nolinebreak`

The [source code guide](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/source2e.pdf) states that `\nolinebreak` is implemented by multiplying its input parameter `penalty` by (-1) and passing the result into `\nopagebreak`.

I haven't found documentation on how to use the command.

Comment: Perhaps here [(http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/breaking.htm#nolinebreak)] and here [(https://latexref.xyz/)]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94217/what-is-the-difference-between-nobreak-and-nolinebreak

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

The [LaTeX2e source](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) fails to emphasize that `\linebreak` and `\nolinebreak` deals with *horizontal* list output, while `\pagebreak` and `\nopagebreak` deals with *vertical* list output. It's just mentioned to be analogous.

[image]

Here is the code for `\linebreak`, from [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co):

```
\def\linebreak{\@testopt{\@no@lnbk-}4}
\def\nolinebreak{\@testopt\@no@lnbk4}
\def\@no@lnbk #1[#2]{%
  \ifvmode
    \@nolnerr
  \else
    \@tempskipa\lastskip
    \unskip
    \penalty #1\@getpen{#2}%
    \ifdim\@tempskipa>\z@
      \hskip\@tempskipa
      \ignorespaces
    \fi
  \fi}
```

From this we see that both `\linebreak` and `\nolinebreak` calls `\@no@lnbk` internally. Calling `\linebreak` results in the first argument of `\@no@lnbk` to be a negative `-`, while `\nolinebreak` doesn't supply a first argument (or leaves it empty). In fact, `\nolinebreak` is equivalent to `\linebreak[4]`.

Within `\@no@lnbk`, a test is made to ensure you're not in [`v`ertical `mode`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13177/5764) (`\ifvmode`). If you are in vertical mode, `\linebreak` and `\nolinebreak` will result in an error (`\@nolnerr` or "There's no line here to end."). The following example replicates this failure:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum

\linebreak

\end{document}
```

If you are not in vertical mode, the `last` `skip` is stored, undone (`\unskip`) and a `\penalty` is inserted. Penalties can increase or decrease the "badness" of what is being set on the page. Inserting a negative penalty (when you're using `\linebreak`) reduces the badness and therefore encourages a breaking point, while a positive penalty (when using `\nolinebreak`) increases the badness and therefore discourages a breaking point.

Once the penalty has been inserted, the original skip is replaced (and subsequent spaces inserted in the code is ignored (`\ignorespaces`). The penalty has to be inserted before the skip to avoid visually-odd breaking points.

---

`\linebreak` is equivalent to `\linebreak[4]`, while

- `\linebreak[0]` inserts `\penalty -0` (not necessary);
- `\linebreak[1]` inserts `\penalty -\@lowpenalty` (`\penalty -51`);
- `\linebreak[2]` inserts `\penalty -\@medpenalty` (`\penalty -151`);
- `\linebreak[3]` inserts `\penalty -\@highpenalty` (`\penalty -301`); and
- `\linebreak[4]` inserts `\penalty -\@M` (`\penalty -10000`)
- `\nolinebreak` inserts `\penalty \@M` (`\penalty 10000`)

Answer (score 0):

See Sec. 9.8, [`texdoc latex2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/latex2e-help-texinfo). There is an online version on [latexref.xyz](http://latexref.xyz). If you are interested in topic `penalty`, you can read TeX related books like *The TeXbook* and *TeX by Topic*.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the command description in the LaTeX manual or in the LaTeX companion.

From the LaTeX manual (page 95):

> Although unwanted line breaks are usually prevented with the `~` and `\mbox` commands described in Section 2.1.1, LaTeX also provides a `\nolinebreak` command that forbids TeX from breaking a line at that point. Like the `\linebreak` command, `\nolinebreak` takes a digit from `0` to `4` as an optional argument to convert the prohibition into a suggestion that this isn't a good place for a line break—the higher the number, the stronger the suggestion. A `\nolinebreak[0]` command is equivalent to `\linebreak[0]`, and `\nolinebreak[4]` is equivalent to `\nolinebreak`.

On page 213:

> `\linebreak[`*num*`]`
>     `\nolinebreak[`*num*`]`
>   The `\linebreak` command encourages and `\nolinebreak` discourages a line break, by an amount depending upon *num*, which is a digit from `0` to `4`. […]