# Create a page (text) wide text box in twocolumn document

Tags: two-column

#### Background

I'm typesetting a book for which I use `twocolumn` declaration in the `documentclass` (it's a very long science book with many tables and figures so I didn't want to redeclare the twocolumn env. after every fullwidth image/table so I chose the document class way).

#### The problem

At the start of each `chapter`, there's a quote which I would like to keep onecolumn (ie. at the width of `\textwidth`), so I don't have it only in the 1st column but rather above both of the columns. So far I've tried `minipage` environment and `\parbox` which both do give me a box with width of `\textwidth`, but the second column isn't pushed lower beneath the quote box  so it overflows it. When I've tried a hack using

```
\begin{table*}
The text of the quote
\endtable*}
```

the quote displayed as I wanted above both columns but at the next page, not right under the chapter heading. When I've tried to use `\Floatbarrier` from placeins package, the 2nd column overflown the quote as with the other solutions.

My current setup (posting only MWE here, I have lots of other packages loaded which, I believe, are irrelevant to this) which gives me the undesired result of the quote being in only the 1st column, not above both the columns, is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany,twoside,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % using only for this MWE

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet} % (fold)
        \textit{This is the text of a very insightful and deep quote that affects lives of all beings.}
        \begin{flushright}
            Konfucius
        \end{flushright}
        \medskip
        \lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Which results in this when compiled in Lualatex:

[image]

#### Question

Is there any way I can produce this desired result in Latex?

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With use of the macro `strip` from the package `cuted`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany,twoside,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{dblfloatfix} 
\usepackage{cuted}  % <---

\usepackage{lipsum} % using only for this MWE

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet} % (fold)
    \begin{strip}   % <---
        \textit{This is the text of a very insightful and deep quote that affects lives of all beings.}
        \begin{flushright}
            Konfucius
        \end{flushright}
    \end{strip}    % <---
        \medskip
        \lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is the simplest solution to my problem which works like a charm and since the 2 first answers are essentially the same, I'm accepting yours because it came earlier. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Note: in Lualatex 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian), there need to be empty lines around the `\epigraph{}{}` line, otherwise Lualatex will throw an arror: `! You can't use \prevdepth in horizontal mode. \nointerlineskip ->\prevdepth`

Comment: @edison23 Is this a bug? In any case thank you!

Comment: No, that's not a bug. LaTeX needs to be in [vertical mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13177/what-are-vertical-and-horizontal-modes) when it's handling vertical spacing. If you don't add the blank lines, LaTeX stays in horizontal mode, hence the error. (But I have no idea why older versions of LuaLaTeX didn't require this... so yes, there might be some bug around but I feel it might rather be in the older versions.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `strip` environment, I would recommend using the `epigraph` package, which can easily be adapted to your taste:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany,twoside,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
 \usepackage{cuted}
 \usepackage{epigraph}
 \setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.75\textwidth}
 \renewcommand{\textflush}{flushright}
 \setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
 \setlength{\beforeepigraphskip}{0pt}
 \setlength{\afterepigraphskip}{0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum} % using only for this MWE

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet} % (fold)

\begin{strip}
\epigraph{\itshape This is the text of a very insightful and deep quote that affects lives of all beings.}{Konfucius}
\end{strip}
        \lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the `strip` environment works like a charm and thanks for proposing the `epigraph` but is there a way I can make the horizontal line between the quote and the author only e.g. `0.4\textwidth` wide?

Comment: Yes, in several ways. For instance you can remove the line `\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}` in your preamble and replace it  with: `\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@epirule}{\rule[.5ex]{0.4\textwidth}{\epigraphrule}}
\makeatother`

Comment: Thanks, I've modified the setting so it aligns the rule to the right: `\makeatletter \renewcommand{\@epirule}{\begin{flushright}\rule[.5ex]{0.4\textwidth}{\epigraphrule}\end{flushright}} \makeatother`

Comment: I also added negative 1.5em vertical space to remove the big margin above the rule - `\vspace{-1.5em}` - but that's just a matter of taste

Answer (score 1):

This solution modifies `\@makechapterhead` to include the quote, which is stored in a savebox ahead of time by `\chapterquote`.

Note that `flushright` is a list and adds extra space above and below, where as `\makebox` does not.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany,twoside,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % using only for this MWE

\newsavebox{\quotebox}

\newcommand{\chapterquote}[2]% #1==quote, #2=credit
{\savebox{\quotebox}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering\textit{#1}\\%
  \ifx\empty#2\relax\else \makebox[\textwidth][r]{#2}\fi}}\ignorespaces}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@ % gap below title
    \ifvoid\quotebox\else
      \box\quotebox
      \bigskip
    \fi
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapterquote{This is the text of a very insightful and deep quote that affects lives of all beings.}%
        {Konfucius}%
    \chapter{Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet}%
    \lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

---

One can simplify the code somewhat by using the etoolbox package to edit `\@makechapterhead`.

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vskip 40\p@}{%
  \vskip 40\p@ % gap below title
  \ifvoid\quotebox\else
    \box\quotebox
    \bigskip
  \fi}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution is unnecessarily complicated for my usecase... but it may certainly be useful for some other people.

Comment: Technically, the \@makechapterhead definition is already in your code, you just can't see it.

Comment: I know it's there but it's just easier for me to do it using the `strip` environment. There might be cases where I don't have a quote for a chapter and then I'd have to fiddle with the chapter definition again. Anyway, thanks for pointing out the fact about `flushright` adding margins and possibility to use `makebox`, it's actually better that way :)