# Adding indentation after setting \setlength\parindent{0pt}'

Tags: indentation

I am looking for a way to add an indentation after setting `\parindent` to 0. I tried a suitable amount of search, but none really seemed to meet my needs.

I tried to change the command `\indent` by inserting spaces:

```
\renewcommand{\indent}{\hspace{15pt}}
```

However, `\indent` did not add any extra space at the start of a new paragraph.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What kind of indent are you looking for and when and how (automatically or manually) should it be produced?

Comment: I would like to type "\indent" at beginning of a paragraph if needed and have an indentation. Since the indentation length is set by 0, I need to find an alternative method.

Comment: Are you sure that your readers will understand the difference between the two types of paragraphs?

Comment: it seems  a very strange requirement, you should never need \noindent or \indent within the document, such things should be set up by the document class. That said you can use `\hspace*`  so the space is not dropped but I would not redefine the `\indent` primitive, define your own command.

Comment: @egreg it is for my personal use. I am writing math lecture notes in latex and I want to format things this way.

Answer (score 2):

First store the original indent by adding

```
\newlength{\saveparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength}{\saveparindent}{\parindent}}
```

to your preamble. Then also add

```
\newcommand{\indentpar}{\par\hspace*{\saveparindent}\ignorespaces}
```

as your new indentation mechanism.

Assuming you have `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` somewhere else in your document you should now be able to use it in the following way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\saveparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\saveparindent}{\parindent}}
\newcommand{\indentpar}{\par\hspace*{\saveparindent}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

This is an indented paragraph.

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indentation
This is a paragraph that is not indented.

\indentpar
Here is a new indented paragraph.

\end{document}
```

Of course, LaTeX also provides `\noindent`, if you're only interested in some non-indented paragraphs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is an indented paragraph.

\noindent% Remove paragraph indentation just for this paragraph
This is a paragraph that is not indented.

Here is a new indented paragraph.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should always be able to use `\hspace` for this purpose: `\hspace{5mm}`

EDIT:
In order for `\hspace` to work you probably have to switch from vertical to horizontal mode using `\leavevmode`. See [Function and usage of \leavevmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/function-and-usage-of-leavevmode) and [What are vertical and horizontal modes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13177/what-are-vertical-and-horizontal-modes)

So all in all this should work: `\leavevmode\hspace{5mm}`

Comment: Hi Raven. Unfortunately, \hspace{5mm} did not work. It certainly adds an extra space if I use it in the middle of a paragraph. However, once I add a line \\, it doesn't give me an indentation.

Comment: @JamesChung did you use it directly after the `\\` or did you have a blank line in between?

Comment: See also my edited post

Comment: simpler to use `\hspace*`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I ended up redefining \indent as \hspace*{15pt}. Thank you

Comment: @JamesChung as I say, I wouldn't redefine the primitive (things will break)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. Okay, I will define a new command that does /hspace*